# Usage of - operator in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I run this query and it returns 15 products

```
+(+organizationId:6 +(mainGenre:dance alternateGenre:dance) +(state:pending state:published state:accepted)) +(alias:audioProduct)
```

So, it means that there are 15 products of organizationId = 6 AND (Main_Genre=Dance or Alternate_Genre=Dance). However, this query seen below doesn't return anything.

```
+(+organizationId:6 +(-mainGenre:pop -alternateGenre:pop) +(state:pending state:published state:accepted)) +(alias:audioProduct)
```

Now the query is like "organizationId = 6 AND Main_Genre!=Pop AND Alternate_Genre!=Pop". I think it should return at least 15 products. I mean it should return the products which were found for MainGenre:Dance.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `(-mainGenre:pop -alternateGenre:pop)`, the OR operator is implied, i.e. it's equivalent to

`Main_Genre != pop OR Alternate_Genre != pop`

while what you're after is

`Main_Genre != pop AND Alternate_Genre != pop`

You should try this instead (see the `&&` operator):

```
+(+organizationId:6 +(-mainGenre:pop && -alternateGenre:pop) +(state:pending state:published state:accepted)) +(alias:audioProduct)
```

Answer (score 0):

The AND relation is a [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property).
Let `*` be the `AND` relation, and `+` the `OR` relation, `A`,`B` and `C` three properties.
Then: `A*(B+C) = A*B + A*C` 
Your statement means: 
(organizationId = 6 **AND** Main_Genre!=Dance) **OR** (organizationId = 6 **AND** Alternate_Genre!=pop)